# Thymeleaf Modify and Post Current Object

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a form and post data into controller via Thymeleaf:

```
<form action="lia.html" th:action="@{/lia}" th:object="${myRequest}" method="post">
```

At another place of my html page, if a user click a particular button, I want to modify that object and send it to same controller.

I have already that object which has been initialised. Button is not a part of any form. How can I send that object into a controller with Thymeleaf.

**PS:** I know that I can send it via Javascript or put such buttons into a form but I want to learn the Thymeleaf way.

Comment: When you say the "Thymeleaf way" you understand that Thymeleaf is just a markup language to format HTML so there is no way to do anything dynamic specifically with markup.  You would just have to use a straight HTML form which posts data and then goes to a new page.  Does this make sense?  I am not sure what you are asking for here.

Comment: Thymeleaf has capabilities something like Spring EL. It just not generate HTML but also can fill a model at MVC.

Comment: Hmm, I looked briefly at their documentation and everything there is referring to templating and I don't see anything about client side which is what I assume you are asking about.  Did the answer below help?  I am still not really clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thymeleaf only has th:object, th:field and forms.  When you start talking about modifying objects outside of forms, thymeleaf doesn't have any support for stuff like that (and it isn't intended to solve those problems).  At this point, you are just looking at whatever spring offers to solve those problems.

Comment: Could be nice to get a solution from Spring side?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only similar approach to what you're looking for is using bind with Spring EL expressions.

> Thanks to the advanced form-field binding capabilities in Spring MVC,
>   we can use complex Spring EL expressions to bind dynamic form fields
>   to our form-backing bean. This will allow us to create new Row objects
>   in our SeedStarter bean, and to add those rows’ fields to our form at
>   user request.

Take a look the next link, where is good example:

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields

- The button

  ```
  <button type="submit" name="removeRow" 
              th:value="${rowStat.index}" th:text="#{seedstarter.row.remove}">Remove row</button>
  ```
- Request Mapping

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value="/seedstartermng", params={"removeRow"})
  public String removeRow(
      final SeedStarter seedStarter, final BindingResult bindingResult, 
      final HttpServletRequest req) {

      final Integer rowId = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("removeRow"));
  seedStarter.getRows().remove(rowId.intValue());
      return "seedstartermng";
  }
  ```