# Thymeleaf: get an object from form

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Let's say I have an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Building")
@Data
public class Building {

@Id
@Column(name = "buildingId")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer buildingId;

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}
@JoinColumn(name = "buildingType")
private BuildingType buildingType;
 //...

}
```

In my controller I put all building types into the model:

```
@RequestMapping("/addBuilding")
    public String newBuilding(Model model, @ModelAttribute Building building){
       model.addAttribute("buildingTypes", buildingTypeService.getBuildingTypes()); //gives me an ArrayList<BuildingType>
}
```

Now I want to iterate over the building types to put them in drop down `<select>`:

```
<form class="some-form" method="post" th:action="@{/addBuilding}">
    <select id="type" class="some-class" required>
        <option th:each="buildingType : ${buildingTypes}" th:text="${buildingType.name}"></option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="button">Store</butto>
</form>
```

This works fine. But when I try to get the chosen building type:

```
<form class="some-form" method="post" th:action="@{/addBuilding}" th:object="${building}">
        <select id="type" class="some-class" th:field="*{buildingType}" required>
            <option th:each="buildingType : ${buildingTypes}" th:value="${buildingType}" th:text="${buildingType.name}"></option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Store</button>
</form>
```

My controller does not receive an object but a String:

```
@RequestMapping("/addBuilding")
        public String newBuilding(Model model, @ModelAttribute Building building){
           //...
           System.out.println((building.getBuildingType() instanceof BuildingType)); //false
    }
```

Is it possible to get an object from Thymeleaf ? Or is it neccessary to create a primitive transient field (e.g. String) for BuildingType, return it from Thymeleaf and search in controller for BuildingType based on this field ?

Comment: Thymeleaf doesn't exist from the client onwards (client, your controllers). Thymeleaf is a template engine. Now, the way Spring (not thymeleaf) allows you to recieve objects in your controller is based on the html element's names. So if you've an input with name="x", and another with name="y", and in your controller you are mapping an object with x and y attributes, it will be filled. On a sidenote, thymeleaf's "th:field" basically sets the name for the input when the html is processed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thymeleaf Modify and Post Current Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020127/thymeleaf-modify-and-post-current-object)